# Change the icon when you click MDIconButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivymd

could you tell me how to make clicking the button (MDIconButton) change the icon.
I tried this by changing the icon variable:

```
class MyButton(MDIconButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.icon = "path to first image"
        self.alternative = "path to second image"
        self.icon_size = 300
        self.radius = 30
        self.size_hint = [.05, .05]

    def on_press(self):
        self.icon, self.alternative = self.alternative, self.icon
```

But after that the alignment is lost and the icon goes to the bottom left corner and there is no way to change it.

Please help me so much.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example contains an `MDIconButton`, whose icon changes after clicking it, while keeping its original size and position, as intended.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<UpdateIcon>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDIconButton:
        id: iconButton
        icon: 'language-python'
        pos_hint: {'x':.5, 'y':.5}
        size_hint: (.05, .05)
        icon_size: '300sp'
        on_press: root.updateIcon('android')
 ''')

class UpdateIcon(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateIcon,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def updateIcon(self, newIcon):
        self.ids.iconButton.icon = newIcon
        
class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Change Icon"
        return UpdateIcon()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```